# How to refresh the UIImagePickerController when changes are made to files in Camera Roll?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController that is used to pick images. I am having an issue where when the app is put in the background when the UIImagepickerController is navigated to a folder and changes are made to the camera roll items (add, delete, edit) these changes are not reflected in the UIImagePickerController when I return to the app and continue picking.

Is there a way to refresh the contents at that path when the app is put in foreground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be there is not any method or property of `UIImagePickerController` which use for reload. But you can achieve it by destroy and recreate the picker. This will refresh the all images available but will lose any current selection / scroll position. Here I mention that, **it is not a good idea.** But may be there is no other way.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. But would there be any way to at least re-navigate to folder?

Comment: @EdAbe - Just try with above mine suggestion surly its working for you. THanks :)

Comment: it is working for even if I just navigate out of the folder. But I want to avoid the user picking an image that has been edited or even deleted accidently. Your solution is working for me. And it is what I am implementing but I need more of a permanent solution.

Comment: OKAY..well,  Your idea is good,, but i don't know about it so i can not give any suggestion on it. Not sure but my experience saying that it might be not possible to find that image is editing or not ? But don't give up , your try will be the best.. keep it up :) All D Bst :)